# How to print the number of columns and lines in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I am a Python newbie so this might sound like a silly question, but I have a CSV file and I want my script to print the number of lines and the number of columns in the file. This is my script:

```
import csv

op = open(Test06242015.csv)
rd = csv.reader(op)


for row in rd:
    list = []
    list.append(row)
    print list
    for items in row:
        print len(row)

op.close()
```

I am actually getting the right answer (320), but it prints out 320 times for each row (below):

```
[['19.385', '19.227', '18.308', ...]]
320
320
320
320
320
320
320
320
(...and it keeps going)
```

How can I make it so that 320 only prints out once? Also, how can I read the number of rows as well?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the length of row inside the inner loop, try printing it outside the inner loop.

Example -

```
for row in rd:
    list = []
    list.append(row)
    print list
    for items in row:
        pass # or whatever other logic you want, if you do not want to do anything remove this loop
    print len(row)
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems so obvious now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('Test06242015.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    line = next(reader, [])
    remaining = len(reader)
    print len(line)  # Number of columns
    if line:
        remaining += 1
    print remaining  # Total numer of rows.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be printing just the row and its length, not the entire list on each row and the row's length for every column.

```
counter = 1
for row in rd:
    print counter, len(row), row
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use pandas which is incredibly fast to get the information you need:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
print(df.shape)
```

#Output

#(number or rows, number of columns)